# How to set the size of my Dialog depends on the MainWindow (MVVM wise)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

can you tell me how can i set the width of my usercontrol (which should depends on the mainwindow). via PRISM?

I tried to use the Application.Current.Window.Width in Xaml but it doesnt work there.

Here is my code:

```
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ShowExpressionHelpWindowNotificationRequest}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
             <vm:SpreadSheetUserControl Width="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current.MainWindow.Width}}"/>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

Any non prism solution is okay too.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ShowExpressionHelpWindowNotificationRequest}">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        xmlns:win="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <vm:SpreadSheetUserControl Width="{Binding Path=MainWindow.Width, Source={x:Static win:Application.Current}}"/>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

Comment: Hi Dude. Thx for the answer it works. But do you know why did it work? I really want to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: The Path of the Binding specifies the actual property to bind to and the source specified the type where this property is defined. You binding source was invalid.